# Efficiency of heat exchanger

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

During the practical work we were studying singular, multibular and plate heat exchangers, for all of them we got efficiency more than 100%, is it possible or what affects to efficiency?
We calculated heat efficiency by dividing heat balance of cold water to heat balance of hot water.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Heat exchanger efficiency is generally defined as its “effectiveness” in transferring a given amount of heat from one fluid at a high temperature to another fluid at a lower temperature; this is the actual amount heat transferred divided by the optimum amount of heat that can be transferred.  For a counter flow heat exchanger, the optimum is achieved when $T_{hot \enspace in} = T_{cold \enspace out}$ where $T_{hot \enspace in}$ is the inlet temperature of the fluid to be cooled and $T_{cold \enspace out}$ is the outlet temperature of the fluid that receives the heat.  The actual amount of heat transferred is less because $T_{hot \enspace in} > T_{cold \enspace out}$.

For details, see numerous on-line descriptions of heat exchanger efficiency.